# Sql Server iteration

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using a `while` loop  to retrieve 5 values.

At the end of the loop I want to add all the values up to produce a total.

e.g.

- ITERATION_1 = 5
- ITERATION_2 = 8
- ITERATION_3 = 2
- ITERATION_4 = 3
- ITERATION_5 = 2

So the total would be 20

This is what I have so far:

```
WHILE(@PROJECT_SEQ>0)
BEGIN

    SELECT @PROJ_ID=PROJECT_ID FROM #TmpProjects WHERE SEQ_NO=@PROJECT_SEQ


    SELECT COUNT(idDP_Entity_Activity)AS COUNT1 FROM DP_Project_Details PD
    INNER JOIN DP_Initiation I
        ON I.FK_Project_ID=PD.Project_ID
    INNER JOIN DP_Entities E
        ON E.FK_Project_ID=PD.Project_ID
    INNER JOIN DP_Entity_Activity EA
        ON EA.FK_idDP_Entities=E.idDP_Entities
    WHERE PD.Project_ID=@PROJ_ID




    --SET @COUNT=@COUNT+@COUNT
    --SELECT @COUNT,@PROJ_ID

    SET @PROJECT_SEQ=@PROJECT_SEQ-1

END
```

Comment: Why would you do this in a loop instead of just writing it as a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely an easier method would be to just count the projects up like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(idDP_Entity_Activity)AS [TOTAL_PROJECT_COUNT]
    FROM DP_Project_Details PD
    INNER JOIN DP_Initiation I
        ON I.FK_Project_ID=PD.Project_ID
    INNER JOIN DP_Entities E
        ON E.FK_Project_ID=PD.Project_ID
    INNER JOIN DP_Entity_Activity EA
        ON EA.FK_idDP_Entities=E.idDP_Entities
    WHERE PD.Project_ID in (Select Project_ID From #TmpProjects 
                            Where Seq_No <= @PROJECT_SEQ)
```

Comment: @Barry...Thanks dude, this logic didn't click on my mind. I was thinking in a totally diff way. Thanks a lot!!!!